# Can someone explain the ellipses tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, ambiguous-tags

There is no tag wiki on the "Ellipses" tag...and I can't figure out what it means exactly. There are [questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis) with this tag that as far as I can tell don't have anything to do with the use of the ellipse, but...is somehow connected. (ie. an ellipse is used at some point in the question, or the question revolves around some sort of omission.) If anything I think there needs to be some clarification on this tag and when it should be used...

(PS I used them on purpose...I couldn't pass it up, but it's an honest question.)

Comment: Not only that there is no tag wiki for "ellipses", but there is no such tag.

Comment: silvermaple: Putting sawa’s comment in a plain language :), you are misspelling the tag name “ellipsis” as “ellipses.”  By the way, “ellipse” usually refers to a [completely different thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse).

Comment: Thanks Tsuyoshi! I'm pretty bad at spelling in English even thou it's my native language.

Comment: @silvermaple: I am pretty bad at writing kanji in Japanese even though Japanese is my native language.  Oh, my!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain the ellipses tag?

It is better if it is explained in a tag wiki excerpt, but in the meanwhile, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).

*Update*: Added a [tag wiki](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/ellipsis/info).

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much more sense now!